# Prove $\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ by expanding its infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How can I prove that
$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
by expanding the infinite product
$$\sin x=x\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)?$$

**What I tried**

Expanding
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{1^2\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2^2\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3^2 \pi^2}\right)\cdots$$
gives
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots\right)+\frac{x^4}{\pi^4}\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^2 3^2}+\cdots\right)+\cdots$$
The first term in the parentheses is $\pi^2/6$, so
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+???$$
I'm unable to determine the **general** term in the infinite series in this way.

Comment: Prove that the product $P$ expands to a power series, then prove that $P'' = -P$.

Comment: @reuns But how can I prove $P''=-P$?

Comment: @reuns Expanding the product to a power series is the whole point of this question.

Comment: It is easy to see that $P$ is equal to *some* power series, starting with $x+c x^3$, if we can show that $P''=-P$ then we easily get the usual $\sin x$ power series. The difficulty is to prove that $u'+u^2=-1$ where $u=(\log P)' = \sum_n \frac1{x-\pi n}$. To compute $u^2$ we use $\frac1{(x-n)(x-m)} = \frac{1/(n-m)}{x-m}+\frac{1/(n-m)}{x-n}$ but conditional convergence makes it a bit trickier than it seems. Perhaps showing instead that $u''+2uu' = 0$ is a better idea.

Comment: @reuns How can I show that $u''+2uu'=0$?

Comment: See what you get when doing a partial fraction decomposition of the $\frac1{(x-\pi n)(x-\pi m)^2}$ terms of $uu'$

Comment: @reuns Why are you trying to do the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{(x-\pi n)(x-\pi m)^2}$?

Comment: @reuns And how does the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{(x-n)(x-m)}$ help at computing $u^2$?